# Is it possible to add child nodes to the added custom nodes

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

the actual procees of my work is initially i will have a root node for a treeview. If i right click on that i will have a context menu with some options. If i select add new from that i will add a text file as child node to the root node. This works fine . After adding that text file i would like to add a child node under that text file..

The over all flow will be

Initially when page loads my treeview will be with a single rootnode

ACH

If i add a text file i would like to show my treeview as follows

```
ACH

 |-> some.txt

|->A( Child for some.txt)

   |->B(child for  A) 

       |->C(Child for B)
```

Up to A i was succeded but i do not know how to add the remaining also i would like to set image index for the custom child nodes added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep a reference to the node A and call Add on its Nodes property:

```
TreeNode nodeA = nodeACH.Nodes.Add("A");

TreeNode nodeB = node1.Nodes.Add("A");

TreeNode nodeC = node1.Nodes.Add("B");
```

Comment: The image is getting changed how to set this

Comment: You have to set the ImageList property on your Treeview, and set for each node its ImageIndex property to reference the image

Comment: I set the property but initially it's loading the default one and when i click on the ndoe the image is getting changed

Comment: You will find here all the infos you need about the TreeNode class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx
You have to set the SelectedImageIndex property to define which image you want to display when the node is seledted